# How do I get the ID of selected datalist

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have just figured out how to populate a datalist element from mysql. I need to get the associated ID that corresponds to the selected value to submit to another page.  I can submit the value, but I need the ID.  I hope it is a simple syntax error, but I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advnace.

```
<?php

require 'connect_mysqli.php';

$sql = "SELECT street FROM streets";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
?>
<form action="new.php" name="test" method = "post">
<datalist id="street" name="streets">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['street']; ?>"><?php echo $row['street_id']; ?></option>
    <?php 
    } 
?>

</datalist>
<input type="text" name="street" id="test" autocomplete="off" list="street">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<?php 
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: Sorry..My Bad...Yes..Exactly you only selected the `street` column from your database so that's why `street_id` is not there..! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I think you are doing wrong to submit value of street. Change it to this

```
  <option value="<?php echo $row['street_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['street']; ?></option>
```

It will display street name and submit street id And get value like this

```
$_post["streets"];// I haven't used datalist but if works it would be this
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT street FROM streets";
```

> *"I hope it is a simple syntax error"*

You didn't make a syntax "error", you just didn't select the `street_id` column in your query, that's why it's not showing in the dropdown, in regards to `$row['street_id']`.

You need to add it in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT street, street_id FROM streets";
```

N.B.: Column selection are separated by commas. You can further add to the query if you wish, but make sure there isn't a trailing comma following the last column chosen.

I.e: This would FAIL:

```
$sql = "SELECT street, street_id, col3, FROM streets";
```

However, `$row['street_id']` and `$row['street_ID']` are two different animals altogether here. So, make sure that that is the letter-case used. They are case-sensitive when it comes to looping over column names, and that would trigger an error when checking for them, being something to the effect of an unexisting column.

Sidenote:

I didn't see a closing `</form>` tag in your posted code. Make sure it's part of your real code.

---

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: OK, I fixed the query and added the </form> tag.  The datalist is now displaying the street and the ID in 2 columns. How do I get the ID not to show? Also, I cant get the ID on the other page.                             <?php
echo $street = $_POST['street'];
echo $id = $_POST['street_id'];
?>

Comment: @RobAlston You're using `$_POST['street']` where it should be `$_POST['streets']` as per the named attribute here `<datalist id="street" name="streets">`

Comment: @RobAlston you also don't have a name attribute for that `$_POST['street_id'];`. You should have posted your full code from the beginning.  So, I don't know which element you want to use that from.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to include the `street_id` column in the columns you are selecting from the streets table.

**Change this line:**

```
$sql = "SELECT street FROM streets";
```

**to this line:**

```
$sql = "SELECT street, street_id FROM streets";
```

Comment: I said that 5 hours prior to this; why the answer?